# C++ Merge Sort Visualizer

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, vector

I am trying to make a c++ console application that tries to show you how merge sort looks like. I understand merge sort, and I created a program that organizes a vector of strings called sort_visualize, and each string in it is filled with many #. This is completely randomized for every string. The merge sort will organize them depending on length, instead of the traditional number organizing people do with it. Every time I make a change to the vector, I also clear the screen and print out the entire vector through a draw function, to give the effect of it actively visualizing the sort every frame. The problem is that when I use the draw function to print out the entire sort_visualize string, it does not print out any changes that I have made to it, and prints out the same thing over and over again until the end, when it finally prints the sorted order. What is going on? I Don't understand. I even tried changing the draw(sort_visualize) to draw(sort_visualize_), and that shows small areas of the vector it is working on. Makes no sense. Please try this code and tell me any solutions. Thank you.
 Here's the code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "windows.h"
using namespace std;


void merge_sort(vector<string> &sort_visual_);
void merge_halves(vector<string>&left, vector<string>& right, vector<string>& sort_visual_);
void draw(vector <string> &sort_visual_);

vector <string> sort_visual;

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    //vector

    vector<int> num_list;

    //fill vector with random integers
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        num_list.push_back(rand() % 40);

    //Fill the visualizer strings which will be bars with #'s
    for (int i = 0; i < num_list.size(); i++)
    {
        sort_visual.push_back("");
        string temp;
        for (int j = 0; j < num_list.at(i); j++)
        {

            temp.push_back('#');
        }
        sort_visual.at(i) = temp;
    }

    draw(sort_visual);
    system("pause");

    //sort function
    merge_sort(sort_visual);

}



void merge_sort(vector<string> &sort_visual_)
{

    //dont do anything if the size of vector is 0 or 1.
    if (sort_visual_.size() <= 1) return;

    //middle of vector is size/2
    int mid = sort_visual_.size() / 2;

    //2 vectors created for left half and right half
    vector<string> left;
    vector<string> right;

    //divided vectors
    for (int j = 0; j < mid; j++)
    {
        left.push_back(sort_visual_[j]); //add all the elements from left side of original vector into the left vector

    }
    for (int j = 0; j < (sort_visual_.size()) - mid; j++)
    {
        right.push_back(sort_visual_[mid + j]);//add all the elements from right side of original vector into the right vector
    }


    //recursive function for dividing the left and right vectors until they are length of 1
    merge_sort(left);
    merge_sort(right);
    //do the actual merging function
    merge_halves(left, right, sort_visual_);
}


void merge_halves(vector<string>&left, vector<string>&right, vector<string>& sort_visual_) //pass in 3 vectors
{

    // sizes of each vector (left and right)
    int nL = left.size();
    int nR = right.size();

    //declaring variables pointint to elements for each vector. i will represent finished produce vector
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    //as long as j and k are less than the left and right sizes
    while (j < nL && k < nR)
    {

        if (left[j].length() < right[k].length()) //if the string in the left vector is smaller than string in right vector
        {
            sort_visual_[i] = left[j];//ad the string from left vector in the sort_visuals vector(which is the final product)
            j++;//increment j to move on


        }
        else
        {
            sort_visual_[i] = right[k];//otherwise add the string from right vector in the sort_visual vector

            k++; //increment k to move on

        }
        i++; //i is the final vector, and we have to increment it to set it up to take in the next number


        system("CLS");
        draw(sort_visual);
        Sleep(15);

    }

    while (j < nL)
    {
        sort_visual_[i] = left[j];
        j++; i++;


        system("CLS");
        draw(sort_visual);
        Sleep(15);
    }

    while (k < nR)
    {
        sort_visual_[i] = right[k];
        k++; i++;

        system("CLS");
        draw(sort_visual);
        Sleep(15);
    }



}

void draw(vector <string> &sort_visual)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sort_visual.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << sort_visual.at(i) << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the olden days, we called this debugging:  showing how the sort is performing (like the contents of the arrays at each step/swap).

Answer (score 0):

In merge_halves you work on sort_visual_ but draw sort_visual which is a global that does not seem to be changed. Make sure there are no globals and it will be harder to make mistakes.

Comment: Isn't `sort_visual_` just a reference to `sort_visual`?

Comment: Good point, it is reference, but still better to keep things local.

Comment: My point is that the original is being modified because the local variable is just a reference to that original vector, no?

Comment: I agree with you, and my point is that if you have globals it is very confusing and easy to make a mistake like I did and think they were separate objects when they aren't.

Comment: Turns out you were right, though. Through the recursive calls `merge_sort(left/right)`, `sort_visual_` takes on the `left` or `right` strings. And they are calling `draw` on the original entire string instead of what is now referring to the local `left/right` substring vectors.

Comment: I think I am beginning to understand what you are saying. I tried changing draw(sort_visual) which was a global variable and instead did: draw(sort_visual_) which is the actual vector parameter the function is working with, but now, I get something different. It seems as if it is showing the merge sort process, but it only shows the portion of the vector it is currently sorting. Hence merge sort is called that as it sorts small sections or portions of the list, and merges them together later. I hope I am clear on this. Is there any solution? Thank You!

Comment: Another thing I did was that I modified the draw function to print out the size in numbers of the sort_visual parameter that gets passed in it just to see what's going on, and it does definitely show the merging process. On a vector size of 40, it t outputs these numbers instead of the bars: 2 3 5 10   2 3 5 10   20   2 3 5 10   2 3 5 10   20    40. If this helps on trying to figure out what is happening.